# Way to display “Yesterday”, “Today”

Tags: php, loop, date

I currently use the following code below in my loop to display dates for groups of posts. Works great, was just wondering if it's possible to change the day from php code 'l'(Sunday-Saturday) to Today and Yesterday for the current posts.

I am guessing Wordpress doesn't have a built-in detection and a function will need to be created to replace the date here?

```
$my_date = the_date('l, F jS, Y', '<div class="clear"></div><h2>', '</h2>', FALSE); echo $my_date;
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me less than a minute of asking the googles (or bing, or duck) to find this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454258/php-date-yesterday-today

The accepted answer has the code you want to use (or will give you a starting point).

(And this is not really a WordPress question...it's a PHP question. PHP questions belong on the Stack Overflow place: https://stackoverflow.com/ )

Comment: I found that answer and have been trying to work with it but it I can't get it to work together.

Comment: The code you supplied didn't reference your attempts at using code similar to the link in my answer. All you need to do is to grab the date of the post into a variable (in the correct format) and then use that code (slightly altered) to return the "Today" or "Yesterday" text.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has built-in function to display time difference in a nicer way. And its even used almost everywhere in wp-admin ;)

This function is called [`human_time_diff`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff). It takes two params: `from` and `to` (both as timestamps) and returns a string containing human readable time difference.

And there’s even a filter `human_time_diff` that will allow you to do your alterations to such strings, so you can make it more or less precise (for example the function can return “4 seconds ago”).

And if you want only the “today/yesterday”, then go for Ricks solution with simple comparison of dates.